# How to loop API calls for hierarchy until a condtion is true?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, request, hierarchy

Im trying to figure out the "best" approach to make API calls loop until a condition is met (or if there is a better solutuon.)

The API will provide me with data regarding ultimateBeneficialOwners for a company.
A company can have multiple owners that can be of type: corp or person.

my goal is to gather all information for each found owner, until i find owner(s) that is of `type:person`. then i know i found the top level of owner(s).

lets say i request all owners for company A.

```
const requestResult = await lookupOwners(cinForCompanyA);
```

Company A is owned by Company B so the response looks like this:

```
{
 owners: [
  {
   title: 'Company B',
   type: 'corp',
   cin: 1234,
  }
 ]
}
```

i store that data and now i want to request the data for CompanyB

```
const requestResult = await lookupOwners(1234);
```

and continue this process until the response object has `type: 'person'`.
So lets say the lookup for Company B returns john and Anna as owners:

```
{
 owners: [
  {
   name: 'john',
   type: 'person',
  },
  {
   name: 'anna',
   type: 'person'
 ]
}
```

so to summarise: If the owners is `type: corp`i want to make a new api request for each corp until the response contains a accual person. Then we are done!

Im looking fo a approach that will work regardless if the inital company has 10 levels of owners or 0.

what is a good approach?

Hope this makes sense?

regards
Casper

Comment: Could API return an owner with type `person` and another with type `corp` ? Is there only 1 `corp` at a time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would try to approach this with recursion, just putting each returned cin back into the function until it finds a person. You could also add checks depending on whether every company terminates in a person or if at some point you get a null value or what have you, depends on the specifics of the api you're querying.

```
async function lookup(cin) {
  try {
    const company = await lookupOwners(cin);
    if (company.owners.find((o) => o.type === "person")) {
      return company;
    } else {
      return lookup(company?.owners[0].cin);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}

lookup(cin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) Queue and a while loop. Break out of the while loop as soon as you find an owner while `type: 'person'`. A FIFO queue is easily implemented using an array and using the `.shift()` method to get the first element in line and `.append()` to add elements to the end of the line.

Here is some basic code.

```js
let queue = [companyA];

const foundPerson = false;
const person = null;
while(queue.length > 0 && !foundPerson) {
  const company = queue.shift(); // get the first company in line
  const owners = await lookupOwners(company);
  for(let i = 0; i < owners.length; i++) {
    if(owners[i].type === "person") {
      foundPerson = true;
      person = owners[i];
|   }
    else {
      // if it's not a person, add the company ID to the end of the FIFO queue
      queue.append(owners[i].cin);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your possibilities are complicated by the fact that any one company can have multiple owners... and you didn't guarantee that you could have a mix of people and corp owners...  the following should return an array of all people owners at all levels

```
var companyID = 1234;
var peopleOwnerList = [];
var companyOwnerList = [];
companyOwnerList.push(companyID);
do {
  const requestResult = await lookupOwners(companyOwnerList[0]);
  var ownerList = requestResult.owners;
  while(ownerList.length > 0){
    if(ownerList[0].type == 'person'){
      peopleOwnerList.push(ownerList[0].name);
    }
    else {
      companyOwnerList.push(ownerList[0].cin);
    }
    ownerList.splice(0,1);
  }
  companyOwnerList.splice(0,1);
}
while(companyOwnerList.length > 0);
```